# Guidance on simplifying the following diagram

Tags: database-design, erd

I have a case scenario where a customer can book accommodation or flight only or both.

I have modeled the accommodation part, however i am making things complex by over-thinking how stuff works in real life.

What i have thought is that a customer cannot book a flight because it is referring to a whole aircraft, very unlikely. Therefore i thought that a customer books a flight seat.

The following is what i have done so far, but i have made it too complex.

[image: Flight]

Can someone guide me to make this simpler? Could i merge flight_seat with flight and aircraft? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe some ideas:

a Flight goes from one airport to another.
An Aircraft may be used on a flight, or another may take its place.
The passenger may request a seat,based on the aircraft type

so i would link the flight to the airport directly.
then i would link the aircraft to the flight
the person is booking the flight also... with a requested seat

if you need to model all the way through check-in, then assign the  actual aircraft to the flight, and assign the seat to the passenger.

Comment: actually the only thing in my case scenario is that a customer makes a flight booking and so I obviously thought, "a flight has a destination", so i added airport city and country.